# dataLayer before or after remote script: Google Analytics and TagManager difference

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The [Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/) suggests that the `window.dataLayer` should be populated after/below the remote code script tag.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

However, the [Google Tag Manager documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) suggests the other way around, where `window.dataLayer` is populated before/above the remote code script tag

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [{
    'pageCategory': 'signup',
    'visitorType': 'high-value'
  }];
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
...
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Why the difference?

The Google Analytics code seems especially strange, with what appears to be logic to deal with the `async` attribute on the remote script, which means it could run before or after population of `dataLayer`. Why not just populate `dataLayer` the same way as for Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2):

The second example is showing how to populate `dataLayer` before GTM loads.

The first example assumes you will start with an empty `dataLayer` array. This line `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];` is checking if you've already populated `dataLayer` and using it if so.

Once GTM is loaded you can add more events with `dataLayer.push({...})`